# How can I investigate an exception in console?

Tags: laravel

I have created a console command that requires two dependencies:

public function __construct(LoopInterface $loop, ClientImpl $asteriskClient)
    {
        parent::__construct();

```
    $this->loop = $loop;
    $this->asteriskClient = $asteriskClient;
}
```

I have written a service provider for both of these. I know that the one for the client is working (since it isn't new and I've used it before), but here is how I've added the React event loop:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use React\EventLoop\Factory;

class ReactLoopServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $loop = Factory::create();
        $this->app->bind('React\EventLoop\LoopInterface', $loop);
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return 'React\EventLoop\LoopInterface';
    }
}
```

And here is how I've registered it:

```
'providers' => [
    App\Providers\PamiServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\ReactLoopServiceProvider::class,
]
```

However, when I run my command (`php artisan app:push-server -vvv`), I get this output:

```
  [ErrorException]
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

As you can see, there's no traceback here. How can I investigate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the `-vvv` and `--debug` options do not print out the traceback, the log at `storage/logs/laravel.log` is updated and contains the traceback.